# How to migrate ASP.NET Web Forms application from Membership to ASP.NET Identity 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I have an application which is in .NET Framework version 4.5. It uses Web Forms and EntityFramework 6.1.1.

The EntityFramework's Context object is of type `ObjectContext`. I'm using ASP.NET Membership(the MembershipProvider is customized i.e Custom Membership) for managing the user account related operations.

```
I want to migrate my Web Forms application to ASP.NET Identity.
```

According to http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity article I think I have to do the following things to migrate to the ASP.NET Identity:

1. Convert the ObjectContext to DbContext(and correct the related codes)
2. Create the new tables needed for ASP.NET Identity and do the data migration.
3. Redefine the account section codes and other dependent codes as needed to match the business logic.(optional)

I have few questions in my mind:

1) I have customized the membership `User` table and there are several custom foreign keys associated with the `User` table. Will it still be feasible to migrate to the Identity system without losing any data?

2) As I'm using EntityFramework so DbContext is needed to migrate to Identity system. Can I use ObjectContext for ASP.NET Identity migration?

3) I'm NOT using all the Membership tables as listed at http://i1.asp.net/media/48109/image006.png?cdn_id=2014-11-11-001. (i.e *aspnet_Applications, aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Paths, aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers, aspnet_PersonlizationPerUser, aspnet_Profile, aspnet_Roles, aspnet_SchemaVersions, aspnet_Users, aspnet_UsersInRoles, aspnet_WebEvent_Events*)

But I am using `Application, User, Role, UserInRole, Profile` tables only. Can I still migrate these table in order to use the ASP.NET Identity?

I'm ready to provide more information you may need to understand my current scenario.

I'm looking for the correct steps to migrate to Identity, any caution I need to take care, any hurdles I will face? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can do those things.

Answer (score -2):

Dave Paquette wrote this http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/12/30/so-you-inherited-an-asp-net-web-forms-application.aspx

This may be the answer to your problem. Once you have integrated your Web Forms project to MVC, there are plenty of guides online to integrate the new Identity 2.0.

Comment: But ASP.NET Identity doesn't need MVC. You can use it in a console application if you're persistent enough. Microsoft provide guides for integrating it in a Web Forms based project http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

Comment: @ta.speot.is the reason I said (unless I misunderstood the question) is because I thought he was trying to convert to MVC